How to pass optimization options such as `read_only=True` to `pandas.read_excel` using `openpyxl` as the engine,?
I want to use pandas.read_excel to read an Excel file with the option engine="openpyxl". However, I also want to pass additional optimization options to openpyxl such as:

read_only=True
data_only=True
keep_links=False

How do I do this?

data_only is an option not an optimisation.

These are already implemented by default. From version 2.2:
def load_workbook(
    self, filepath_or_buffer: FilePath | ReadBuffer[bytes], engine_kwargs
) -> Workbook:
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    default_kwargs = {"read_only": True, "data_only": True, "keep_links": False}

    return load_workbook(
        filepath_or_buffer,
        **(default_kwargs | engine_kwargs),
    )

